# Checking if user has view permission for folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to check that the active user (not effective user) has permission to view a folder. Permission will be asserted through user membership of group. I expected that DriveApp.getAccess(user) would return VIEW or EDIT but it seems to be returning NONE. What should I be doing?

If this test script a folder and file owned by me and shared to another return NONE from getAccess().

```
    function myFunction() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B90FGJizRd-gYTU3ZdsfdsafdsaZTgtNmRiNmQ1NafdsfszE5MWYx');
  Logger.log('owner:'+folder.getOwner().getEmail());
  Logger.log('User:'+Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  Logger.log('Sharing access:'+folder.getSharingAccess());
  var access = folder.getAccess('Lijgfjhg@ngs.co.nz');
   Logger.log('active user access:'+access)
  var editors = folder.getEditors();
  Logger.log('editors #'+editors.length)
  for (i=0;i<editors.length;i++){ Logger.log(editors[i].getEmail())};
 var file =  DriveApp.getFileById('1y-m-mfdsafdsfafbPK_ZVQlPi4');
 Logger.log('file owner:'+file.getOwner().getEmail());
   Logger.log('Sharing access:'+file.getSharingAccess());
   access = file.getAccess('Linda.fGF@dgf.co.nz');
     Logger.log('linda user access:'+access)
        access = file.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
        Logger.log('active user access:'+access)
        Logger.log('editors:'+file.getEditors())
}
```

[13-10-09 10:45:52:562 NZDT] owner:dadfrqwer@dings.co.nz

[13-10-09 10:45:52:622 NZDT] User:dafgrfdewjhf@dings.co.nz

[13-10-09 10:45:52:740 NZDT] Sharing access:PRIVATE

[13-10-09 10:45:52:933 NZDT] active user access:NONE

[13-10-09 10:45:53:154 NZDT] editors #0

[13-10-09 10:45:53:444 NZDT] file owner:dafrykgsdtfwt@dings.co.nz

[13-10-09 10:45:53:600 NZDT] Sharing access:PRIVATE

[13-10-09 10:45:53:899 NZDT] linda user access:NONE

[13-10-09 10:45:54:118 NZDT] active user access:NONE

[13-10-09 10:45:54:244 NZDT] editors:

Comment: You should avoid showing real email address on a public forum...

Comment: How is the script being run? Is this running as a web app (script as service, running as a developer) or something other way?

Comment: I ran this test script from the editor to demonstrate the issue but the operational requirement is for a web app script running as script owner to tell if the script active user has access to a file. The file will be shared to user-group which the user may or may not be a member of.

Answer (score 0):

## getEditors()

According to the documentation:

> If the user who executes the script does not have edit access to the Folder, this method returns an empty array.

Example:

```
function saveLog(textToSave) {
  var logFolderId = "0B1kNObnC3POnR2d2ntubk";
  var logFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(logFolderId);
  if (logFolder.getEditors() === []) {
    return ("User " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + " does not have permission to save files to the log folder https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" + logFolderId );
  } else {
    var fileName = "log.txt";
    var logFile = logFolder.createFile(fileName, textToSave);
    return logFile.getUrl();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to do this would be to use `DriveApp::getAccess()`. But both it and `DriveApp::getEditors()` suffer from the same bug described here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761869#comment2

What should work is what follows:

```
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx-unique folder id here -xxx");
     var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
     var access = folder.getAccess(email); 
 // var access = folder.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()); // this is also valid 
        
        console.log(access.name()); // this wil display a readable version of the Drive.Permission enum
    
    if (access == DriveApp.Permission.FILE_ORGANIZER) {
        console.log("DriveApp.Permission.FILE_ORGANIZER");
      }
      else if (access == DriveApp.Permission.ORGANIZER) {
        console.log("DriveApp.Permission.ORGANIZER");
      }
      else if (access == DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT) {
        console.log("DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT");
      }
      else if (access == DriveApp.Permission.EDIT) {
        console.log("DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT");
      }
      else if (access == DriveApp.Permission.NONE) {
        console.log("DriveApp.Permission.NONE");
      }
      else if (access == DriveApp.Permission.OWNER) {
        console.log("DriveApp.Permission.OWNER");
      }
      else if (access == DriveApp.Permission.VIEW) {
        console.log("DriveApp.Permission.VIEW");
      }
```

As the bug describes, if a user is not explicitly given access to a Team Drive or sub-Team Drive folder but instead inherits their access by virtue of being in a user group, then `getAccess()` and `getEditors()` will not find them or their group.

Answer (score 0):

While the DriveApp API is not working, if you include the Drive API Service (v2) in your project, you can use that interface to get a folder's permission.

```
function getPerm(id) { 
   var data = Drive.Files.get(id, { supportsAllDrives: true });  
   return data.userPermission.role;
}
```

The values returned are described by https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-roles